# Correcting except: pass warnings in python - what exceptions may open and os.remove raise?

Tags: python, python-2.7, error-handling, exception, file-handling

In the following piece of code, `some_path` is a string that corresponds to a path (may be a relative path)

```
def editable(some_path):
    """Safely check whether a file is editable."""
    delete = not os.path.exists(some_path)
    try:
        with open(some_path, 'ab'):
            return True
    except:
        return False
    finally:
        # If the file didn't exist before, remove the created version
        if delete:
            try:
                os.remove(some_path)
            except:
                pass
```

In [open's docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) we read:

> If the file cannot be opened, IOError is raised

Is `IOError` the only possible error I can get (UnicodeError comes to mind, or OSError etc) ?

[os.remove docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.remove) are even more vague:

> If path is a directory, OSError is raised

So what if the file is in use, or protected or...

**UPDATE**: How about `shutil.move` ? This seems to raise yet another `shutil.Error(StandardError)` - if I read [the source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/shutil.py#l265) right

Comment: Actually `issubclass(IOError, OSError) --> True`

Comment: See [PEP 3151](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/). It's about a change that went into Python 3.3, but it also explains in detail the issues with the previous system, which is what you're encountering. Specifically, look at the [list of common errnos](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3151/#appendix-a-survey-of-common-errnos) towards the end of the document.

Comment: @vaultah: thanks I know - I just want to be as specific as possible - so if ` except IOError` is enough I would like to have just that

Comment: @robert: wow I am not the only one to be confused :) Actually I was about to ask a separate question for damned WindowsError - will keep you posted. Anyway - I am at python 2 so I would like just to solve this correctly for the case above - namely avoid the super dangerous `except: pass` and instead just pass the right exception in